# Django Translation on CentOS

Tags: python, django, centos

I have a Django 1.4 project in which I'm starting to utilized the framework's translation capabilities.

I have the translation working locally on my Mac.  I can compile the messages from .po to .mo.  And I see the result on the browser.

But once the code is deployed to one of our CentOS environments, it stops working.  I have installed and linked GNU's gettext on both systems via Homebrew (OSX) and Yum (CentOS).

Below are my translation specific configuration parameters.

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
...
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
...
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
```

**Project structure**

```
proj_root/app/locale/en_us/LC_MESSAGES
```

Another thing to note is I'm doing the translations in the view functions via **ugettext**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a colleague of mine, it turns out the language folder was incorrect.

I had the following on my Mac and worked fine.

```
proj_root/app/locale/en_us/LC_MESSAGES
```

But in order to have it work on the server, I had to rename **en_us** to **en_US** (note the change in case).

```
proj_root/app/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES
```

It turns out the Mac file system is case insensitive, which I wasn't aware of.  That's why **en_us** worked on OSX but not on CentOS.  GNU's **gettext** expects the following format, **xx_XX**.